# didn't send mail body in laravel mail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In laravel based email sending contact didn't send mail body. Only send subject in mail.how to send email body?

I tried

`$message->setBody($daE['message']);`

but didn't work

Controller.php

```
public function contact(Request $request)
{

    $daE = array(
        'name'=> $request->name,
        'email'=> $request->email,
        'subject'=> $request->subject,
        'message'=> $request->message,

    );
    Mail::send('mymail', $daE, function ($message) use($daE)
    {    
        $message->from($daE['email']);
        $message->to('taomihiranga@gmail.com');
        $message->subject($daE['subject']);
        $message->setBody($daE['message']);

    });

    return view('contact');
}
```

Contact.blade.php

```
<form class="row contact_form" action="/contactsend" method="post" 
 id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <div class="col-md-6">{{csrf_field()}}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address'">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Enter Subject" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="1" placeholder="Enter Message" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Message'"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="primary-btn">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

no error messages send mail and can't send email body

Comment: `Mail::send()` probably returns something that indicates what happened, you should check it.

Comment: The first argument of [`Mail::send`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail) would be the name of the view that would create the email body. You do not need to use `setBody` to assign the values.

Comment: i tried it as `$message->setBody($daE['message']);` but didn't work.can you send me a fixed code using my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @aynber said the first argument should be an blade template. Then in the second argument you should pass the data you want to display in the blade template (which is you email body).

So you don't need `setBody()` method because your body is the first argument of your email method, then to customise your body use the second param to inject data.

Here is the link to the detailed doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#basic-usage